# XCTest unit test don't work because of framework signature

Tags: xcode, testing, frameworks, xctest, signature

I've a dynamic framework that doesn't have signature
CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED = NO
CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED = NO
EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY =

Main application that this framework is linked works fine, while tests are failing with code signature requirement.

```html
2016-10-05 17:40:40.034 xctest[46026:374452] The bundle “CoreUnitTests.xctest” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.
2016-10-05 17:40:40.035 xctest[46026:374452] (dlopen_preflight(/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Application-cafxiqfcbbczvkezpwscftqdsllz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CoreUnitTests.xctest/CoreUnitTests): Library not loaded: @rpath/Core.framework/Core
  Referenced from: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Application-cafxiqfcbbczvkezpwscftqdsllz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CoreUnitTests.xctest/CoreUnitTests
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Application-cafxiqfcbbczvkezpwscftqdsllz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Core.framework/Core: required code signature missing for '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Application-cafxiqfcbbczvkezpwscftqdsllz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Core.framework/Core'

    /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Application-cafxiqfcbbczvkezpwscftqdsllz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Core.framework/Core: required code signature missing for '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Application-cafxiqfcbbczvkezpwscftqdsllz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Core.framework/Core'
)
Program ended with exit code: 82
```

Is there a way to disable code signature requirement in test bundle?

Comment: Are use using Carthage?

Comment: No, I'm using cocoa pods to manage dependencies

Comment: Then unfortunately, I have no idea.

Comment: How to do it in Carthage?